# How to create UTC timestamp using XQuery in MarkLogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I feel I must have missed something but I just could not figure out how to create a UTC timestamp in MarkLogic using XQuery. The `fn:current-dateTime` function creates timestamp with timezone offset specified by the OS.

This is trivial using Server-side JavaScript:

```js
new Date().toISOString()

// 2020-02-07T14:43:32.588Z
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust timezone with the appropriate fn functions, like this:

```
fn:adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(fn:current-dateTime(), xs:dayTimeDuration("PT0H"))
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks! You are always so helpful.